# JQTouch with JSON-Template or any other dynamic HTML generator: indexing child divs

Tags: javascript, jqtouch

Flat HTML files work fine with JQTouch. JQTouch goes out and indexes all the child divs. The problem is that using JSON-Template to dynamically builds the divs from after a page load, so JQTouch indexing doesn't happen, so navigation between divs doesn't happen.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

With other JS functions, converting standard functions to JQuery functions has worked, but I'm not excited about touching the JQTouch library.

```
function foo(){
```

becomes

```
$.fn.foo = function() {
```

Any tips?